# Try to get the first element from the empty collection

Tags: java, collections

```
public class Demo {

    private final List<E> blah;

    public demo(final List<E> result) {
        super();
        this.blah = Collections.unmodifiableList(result);
    }

    public List<E> getResult() {
        return blah;
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        final Demo d = new Demo(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
        System.out.println(d.getResult().get(0));
    }
}
```

What happens and why. What is the turaround.?. If i try to do line 1 , is the genericity lost ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your question is conceptually wrong.

Is is rather strange to access element at specific position of a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). This means that you are sure that on a specific position, there is an specific element. An collection is always a group of elements of some type. Accessing only specific element, you give that specific elements some specific meaning. It is good practice to iterate over collection with

```
for(Object o: collection){...}
```

If you want specific access to a specific element like `get(i)` out of a `for`, you always must check if that element exists. Something like

```
if(collection.size() > i)
{
//do operation
}
```

General idea: You can use [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), where elements with specific meaning (keys) are mapped to this meaning (the key).

EDIT: Just checked, [EMPTY_LIST](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#EMPTY_LIST) is immutable, if you want to be able to add elements (and then accessing them with some `get(i)`) you must create it like a normal List

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It will throw and IndexOutOfBoundsException. Why don't you test it?

Answer (score 0):

Test whether it is not empty first... Also EMPTY_LIST isn't type safe.

```
final List<String> list = Collections.emptyList();
if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final List<String> list = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
```

This creates an empty list, that means its size is 0. and after that you called

```
list.get(0)
```

which results ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException